# TomatoUSB Shibby repeater can't connect to main router

Tags: networking, wireless-router, tomato, repeater

I have been trying to setup a [TomatoUSB by Shibby](http://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=164) router as a repeater for the past few hours with no luck. This is my setup:

- **Main Router:** Linksys E3200 running Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-116 K26 USB AIO
- **IP address:** 192.168.0.1
- **IP Range:** 192.168.0.2-50
- **DHCP:** enabled
- **Wireless 2.4 GHz**
- **Name:** MyWifi
- **Mode:** Access Point + WDS
- **Channel Width:** 20 MHz
- **Channel:** 9
- **Security:** WEP/WPA/Disabled (tried them all)
- **WDS:** Link to… (inserted Repeater's MAC address)
- **Repeater:** Linksys E2500 runninng K26 version
- **IP Address:** 192.168.0.2
- **DHCP:** Disabled
- **Wireless 2.4GHz**

Everything same as above, and WDS Link to Main Router's MAC

Again it doesn't seem the repeater is communicating with the main router as my devices are unable to get an IP address

Some screenshots of my Repeater's settings at one point:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is on the Repeater node go into Advanced->Routing and under Miscellaneous change Mode to "Router"